# Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'String()'

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to add a value from DataTable `dtUsers` into a list `UserLocations` however I am getting the title error.

My code is:

```
Public UserLocations As New List(Of String())

For Each NewRow As DataRow In dtUsers.Rows
    Dim seq As String = NewRow("SEQUENCE").Value.ToString
    If CandRow("SQ") = NewRow("SQ") Then
        UserLocations.Add(seq)
    End If
Next
```

I don not understand why I cannot add a string to a list of strings.

How should I go about this?

Comment: Because you define it as an array of string. If you want a string, try this definition: `Public UserLocations As New List(Of String)`

Comment: Oh god, I'm such an idiot. Thank you.

Comment: What is `Value`? `NewRow("SEQUENCE")` returns `System.Object` which has no `Value` property. So that should not even work with `Option Strict Off`. If it's something that can be null you can for example use `NewRow.Field(Of Int32?)("SEQUENCE")`. Now this is a `Nullable(Of Integer)` which has a `Value` property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Public UserLocations As New List(Of String)

For Each NewRow As DataRow In dtUsers.Rows
    Dim seq As String = NewRow("SEQUENCE").Value.ToString()
    If CandRow("SQ") = NewRow("SQ") Then
        UserLocations.Add(seq)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: To Kyvex,I think you should at least thank @muffi  for the answer. At least he provided an explanation.